# SQL Server XML XQuery select where clause attribute

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I have a table with the following content

```
Id | Guid                                 | XmlDefinitionId
 1 | 5a0bfc84-13ec-4497-93e0-655e57d4b482 | 1
 2 | e28e786b-0856-40b6-8189-0fbd68aa3e45 | 1
```

And in another table the following XML structure stored:

```
<ActionActivity DisplayName="DisplayName 1" IsSkipped="False" Id="5a0bfc84-13ec-4497-93e0-655e57d4b482">...</ActionActivity>
<p:Sequence DisplayName="Prerequisites">
    <ActionActivity DisplayName="Inner DisplayName 1" IsSkipped="False" Id="e28e786b-0856-40b6-8189-0fbd68aa3e45">...</ActionActivity>
</p:Sequence>
<ActionActivity DisplayName="DisplayName 2" IsSkipped="False" Id="dcc936dd-73c9-43cc-beb4-c636647d4851">...</ActionActivity>
```

The table containing the XML have the following structure:

```
Id | XML
1  | (XML Structure defined above here)
```

Based on the Guid I want to show the displayname. At the moment I have the following query that returns null at the moment. Later I want for every guid from the first table show the displayname.

```
SELECT 
      Workflow
      ,CAST(Workflow as XML).value('data(//ActionActivity[@Id="73c9-43cc-beb4-c636647d4851"])[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as displayname
  FROM SerializedData
```

Anyone ideas to show the displayname with a sql query?

Comment: Show structure of table containing the XML. Also, sample xml you posted doesn't have `WorkflowActivityId` attribute

Comment: Of what type is XML column in the 2nd table?

Comment: @har07 The XML column is of type XML(.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the XML stored in XML typed column, you can do this way -otherwise you'll need to `CAST` the column to `XML`- :

```
SELECT
    g.guid, x.display_name
FROM GuidTable g
     INNER JOIN 
     (
        SELECT 
            t.id as 'xml_id'
            , c.value('@Id', 'varchar(max)') as 'guid'
            , c.value('@DisplayName', 'varchar(max)') as 'display_name'
        FROM XmlTable t
            CROSS APPLY t.xml.nodes('//ActionActivity') as aa(c)
     ) x on x.guid = g.guid and x.xml_id = g.xmldefinitionid
```

Basically, above query shred the XML at `ActionActivity` node. And then joins shredded data with `GuidTable` on `guid` and `xmldefinitionid` columns.

**output :**

[image]

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/647)**